# XCode doesn't show developer profile, devices, or simulator choices

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-simulator, iphone-developer-program

My Macbook Pro was damaged and I have to take it to Apple to get a new Hard Drive.  The old one would not boot but I was able to recover my projects from it.  I opened a project and actually revoked and reset my certificate, etc in the provisioning portal.  I also reinstalled my device (iPhone) in the organizer.  Everything looks fine in the organizer except nothing shows up under "Developer Profile".

I cleaned all targets also and restarted XCode.

1. The profiles are there in the target
   and projects settings but they are
   grey so I cannot click on them.
2. I only have ios 4.2 as a choice for
   SDK's (No simulator and no iPhone
   even though it's connected and ready
   in the organizer)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by adding the iPhone to the portal.

1. Go to organizer in XCode (Window > Organizer)
2. Right click on the device (iPhone)
3. Select "Add device to provisioning portal"

It will fix these issues!